# C# table rows and columns

Tags: c#

What object can I use that has rows and columns, but not DataTable as it looks like an Excel Table?

Comment: Your question badly needs improvement. I voted to close it since I have no idea what you're asking. For instance, why not use an array?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "looks like an Excel table"?

Comment: Are you looking for a means of **presenting** data, or simply a means of **storing** the data in an object that exposes a collection of "rows" each consisting of several "fields/columns"? There are numerous possible answers to this question - please try to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish. :)

Comment: Also do mean WinForms or ASP.NET? Former: DataGridView, latter GridView

Comment: Sorry, Yes I want to present show the data. Each Entry must be a separate row, with columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `BindingList<T>` or `List<T>`.  BindingList would get my vote, as it is essentially a List with some extra options that enable it to be bound to a datagridview or Listbox very easily.  And it is more light-weight than a DataTable.

Your rows will be each item in the list, and your columns will be the properties of each object that you bind to your viewer, such as a datagridview.  I used this recently with a BindingList and it went very well.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately your options are these:

1. Multidimensional array: `a[i,j] = value`
2. Jagged array: `a[i][j] = value`
3. Indexed array: `a[i+N*j] = value`

Most other classes that I can think of, wrap one of these types of arrays.